# Differential of a metric determinant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, linear-algebra

In Landau Lifschitz (Volume II):

We now derive an expression for the contracted Christoffel symbol $\Gamma_{ik}$ which will be
important later on. To do this we calculate the differential $dg$ of the determinant $g$ made up
from the components of the tensor $g_{ik}$; $dg$ can be obtained by taking the differential of each
component of the tensor $g_{ik}$ and multiplying it by its coefficient in the determinant, i.e. by
the corresponding minor. On the other hand, the components of the tensor $g^{ik}$ reciprocal
to $g_{ik}$ are equal to the minors of the determinant of the $g_{ik}$, divided by the determinant.

$$dg=dg_{ik}\times minor^{ik}$$

$$minor^{ik}=g\times g^{ik}$$
My question is: how to prove it?

Comment: To prove "it". What is "it". Are you asking whether  $dg= g^{ij}dg_{ig}$ or whether $minor^{ij}=g\, g^{ij}$

Comment: An inverse metric is $$g^{ik}=\frac{1}{g}\times Transposed Cofactor Matrix^{ik}$$. Why here is said Transposed Cofactor Matrix=Minor?

Comment: Indeed. The first possible "it" is correct, and the second is not correct.